# В методе onRewardedAdClosed() admob происходит "The webview is destroyed. Ignoring action."

Tags: java, android, admob

Тестовая реклама показывается, но при закрытии рекламы идет ошибка, которая не дает выполнится коду внутри onRewardedAdClosed(), код ошибки:

```
W/Ads: #004 The webview is destroyed. Ignoring action.
```

Пыталась понижать версию библиотеки(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads), но результата не дало

код показа рекламы(в том числе onRewardedAdClosed()):

```
RewardedAdCallback adCallback = new RewardedAdCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onRewardedAdOpened() {
                    // Ad opened.
                }

                @Override
                public void onRewardedAdClosed() {
                    // Ad closed.
                    Log.d(TAG, "onRewardedAdClosed: ");

                    fragmentFirst = new FragmentFirst();

                    clipBody = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction clipUnit = clipBody.beginTransaction();

                    clipUnit.add(R.id.container, fragmentFirst, "fragment_first");
                    clipUnit.addToBackStack(null);
                    clipUnit.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
                    clipUnit.commit();
                }

                @Override
                public void onUserEarnedReward(@NonNull RewardItem reward) {
                    // User earned reward.
                    Log.d(TAG, "onUserEarnedReward: ");

                    // coins++
                }

                @Override
                public void onRewardedAdFailedToShow(int errorCode) {
                    // Ad failed to display
                }
            };
            rewardedAd.show(MainActivity.this, adCallback);
```

log:

```
E/Ads: Google Mobile Ads SDK initialization functionality unavailable for this session. Ad requests can be made at any time.
E/libEGL: validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
E/chromium: [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(222)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE
E/Ads: Invalid event ID: null
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
```

В чем ошибка?

Comment: Уточните конечную цель. Там действительно webView уже уничтожен.

Comment: @Style-7 что в вашем понимание конечная цель?
Если я правильно вас поняла, то конечная цель - это после закрытия рекламы показать окно загрузки файлов с сервера (с помощью фрагмента).

Что с кодом добавления этого окна загрузки, что без него(просто logd) выводится эта ошибка

Comment: Да, правильно, я с фрагментами не работал. Попробуйте сделать в через Handler (будет обновлять в основном потоке) посылая ему сообщения в AdClosed